# stopping a while / for loop when an user says so

Tags: c++

i'm new to c++ so I only kind of know iostream and the syntax of the language.

I am writing a program that creates an infinite amount of .txt files using fstream but i'm kind of stuck, I want it to have a menu in the program so the user could interfere with the process with the help of commands I will code in void functions("pause", "stop", etc...)

It means that the process of creating .txt files should run constantly but that the user could also write in a cin>> the keywords shown above to interfere with the process

I plan to write multiple commands so I'll surely use switch statement in the future but to show you my problem I'll only use a while loop with one command
So I've tried things like that:

```
void stop()
{
return 0;
}

int main()
{
string command= "";
int i=1;

if (command!="stop")
{
     while (i<=2)
     {
     CreateNewFile();
     cin >> command;
     }

} else

{
stop();
}
}
```

But the problem with this kind of loop is that it asks the user to write something everytime in order to reset the loop and it is this thing in particular that I want to avoid...
I want to keep the loop running as long as my user wants it to

I'm sure that the answer is really simple but i've not found any help by asking google so i'll tr to ask you guys.

Thank you in advance to those who will take the time to asnwer me

Comment: The easy option is to ask the user how many files to create, then run the loop that many times.  As the question is phrased, it implies two threads one writing files forever, and the other accepting user input and then stopping other thread.  That's probably too advanced for you at this stage.  Another option is instead of stop having the user press ctrl-c, then deal with that signal.  That might be non-trivial for you too.

Comment: You might be asking how to read keyboard input without blocking.  Or you might be asking how to have the blocking `cin >> command;` run in one thread, while other work happens in another thread.

Comment: Someone (I am cheering for @FlimsyEar665012) will give you the threaded answer to address your original question, while I gave you answer to a different problem.  Upvote my answer if it was helpful, but accept the one that answers your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advise, Adam, is to change your problem description so you ask user how many files they want to create, and then run the loop that many times:

```
for(;;) {
  unsigned n;
  cout << "How many files do you want to create (0 to stop)? ";
  cin >> n;
  if(!n) break;
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    CreateNewFile();
  }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how you phrased the problem or how to solve it with c++.  It's just more complicated answer you seem new at this.

Comment: Keep an eye on @FlimsyEar665012's answer (threads are part of the standard C++ library).

Answer (score 0):

So after a while this is basically the simplest solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
static bool finished = false;
void createFile() {
    while (!finished) {
        //Your code
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string answer;
    std::thread question(createFile);
    std::cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "stop") {
        finished = true;
    }
    question.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Here we create a thread which will keep running until they type stop. I ran the code and it was working I made it print out 1 until I wrote stop.

Comment: i is not incremented in the else case, also, it doesn't answer the question " I want to keep the loop running as long as my user wants it to"

Comment: If we increment the i in the while loop then its going to stop and not be infinite.

Comment: i is read/written by two threads so it needs a mutex.

Comment: I tweaked the code to check but it does the same as my code; you need an user input in order to trigger the createNewFile() function and this is what i'm trying to avoid

Comment: i isn't being shared between the threads. The thread is just there waiting for an answer and once there is an answer and the loop checks if answer is equal to command its going to stop the loop and continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: I don't get.  One threads should be running `for(; command != "stop;) CreateNewFile();` and the other is for(; command != "stop; ) cin >> command.  Wrap the shared variable in a mutex to make it thread safe.

Comment: My bad I am not familiar with the term mutex.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex.  I am not smart to use threads, or maybe too smart not to ;-)

Comment: I was reading and it seems to be that they are to protect the variable from being modified on 2 threads simultaneously but I am only modifying it on one and reading it in the other.

Comment: Same problem with read/write (when the variable is not atomic).

Answer (score 0):

I had something on this line wherein the thread that's doing the actual work continues and only processes commands if the user wants to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <stack>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    std::stack<std::string> commandQueue;
    std::mutex m;
    int i = 0;
    std::thread worker([&]() {
        bool suspend = false;
        while(true) {
            {
                const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
                if(!commandQueue.empty()){
                    std::string command = commandQueue.top();
                    commandQueue.pop();
                    if(command == "continue"){
                        suspend = false;
                        //process continue
                    } else if (command == "pause"){
                        suspend = true;
                        //process other commands....
                    } else if(command == "stop") {
                        //process stop
                        return; //exit thread
                    } 
                }
            }
            //Commands processed, continue as usual
            if(!suspend) {//Process only if not paused
                using namespace std::chrono_literals;
                //Continue creating files or whatever it is that needs to be done continuously
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
                i++;
                //std::cout<<"Value of i is "<<i<<'\n';
                //CreatFileName();
            }
        }
    });
    std::string command;
    do {
        std::cout<<"Enter commands to interact\n";
        std::cin>>command;
        {
            const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
            commandQueue.push(command);
        }
    }while(command != "stop");
    worker.join();
    std::cout<<"After execution, value of i is "<<i<<'\n';
}
```

Of course, the output of *this specific* example is a bit ugly because it is printing to the console from 2 different threads but the commands like `stop`, `pause`, `continue` are processed fine since there's only one thread (the `main` thread) that reads in the commands but since this is just to demonstrate how one can *possibly* achieve what you intend to, I didn't spend up too much time on the output aesthetics.

Comment: ahah thank you for the answer I don't know the half of the libraries you used so I'll come back to this problem later but still thank you lol